# Catalina misses dictionary content and can't download

Tags: catalina, dictionary

I just bought a new MacBookPro. In Dictionary.app on Catalina 10.15.1, One of my dictionaries(The WISDOM English-Japanese dictionary) won't return any result when I look up a word.

I looked into
"/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX/"
and found that there're no AssetData for that dictionary! (Assets for other dictionaries are correctly installed there.)

The Dictionary App nevertheless behaves as if the dictionary were installed, and list it up in the tab.

I toggled the checkbox of the dictionary in preference on/off again and again, restart app, reboot machine, but it never tries to download the dict contents.
I also tried to copy assets from another computer, but I cannot paste them since the System folder is protected.
I tried putting assets to "~/Library/Dictionaries" but the app doesn't recognize it.

Does anyone have similar issue or any idea to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250861549

Comment: It works! Renaming a dictionary did the trick.Thanks so much!